# Empleo de funciones MAX y MIN en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una tabla como la mostrada a continuación (ejemplo simplificado):

ID_Cliente   Pedidos
   1           10
   2           15
   3           5
   4           8

Ahora me gustaría generar una columna extra que fuese el máximo valor de la columna Pedidos, es decir, en las cuatro filas debería aparecer un 15, pero cuando lo intento sólo calcula el máximo de la fila, o sea, que duplica la columna Pedidos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y visitar [ask] para que tus preguntas sean de mayor calidad y mejor recibidas por la comunidad! Podrías añadir el código que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: El código equivalente para este ejemplo sería: SELECT ID_Cliente, Pedidos, MAX(Pedidos) FROM my_table

Answer (score 0):

Tras ver lo que dices en el comentario, creo que lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

```
select ID_Cliente, Pedidos, (select max(Pedidos) 
                             from my_table) as mayor_pedido
from my_table
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Llevas razón, el problema es que (por error mio de no indicarlo) la columna de Pedidos es en realidad un sumatorio proveniente de otra tabla, por lo que al querer llamar a esa tabla desde el nuevo select que me has indicado obviamente esta tabla no existe.

Comment: Añade tu consulta a tu pregunta, de esta manera te podremos ayudar. También te invito de nuevo a hacer el [tour] y mirar [ask] te será útil a la hora de realizar preguntas.